# Subversion for revision history and logging on Source codes

Tags: svn, logging, history, revision, comments

I have tried to find some resource for Subversion how to make revision history and logging message on source code; This question might be a simple

We changed our CVS to Subversion. I am having a problem that how to make Revision history and log message to show on source codes. In CVS , we had used

```
/**
 * Revision:
 *  $Log$
 * 
 *
 *  $Id$
 */
```

to commit to CVS with log message.  I have tried to put "$Revision$ and $Id$" on Source Code to Subversion; however, it does not work to update the Revision history on Source Code.

I used revision mark as follows for Subversion

```
/**
 * Revision:
 *  $Revision$
 * 
 *
 *  $Id$
 */
```

Do you have any idea how to add the revision history and comments to source code when the source code is committed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `svn:keywords` property on the files that you want the keywords replaced in, eg:

```
svn propset svn:keywords "Date Revision Author Id" *.c
```

[(See here)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html)

Answer (score 2):

Subversion does not offer the 'Log' history as an expandable tag.

You do get Id, Date, Revision etc, but you need to set the 'svn properties' -- see 'svn propset' in the manual or help pages.  Good frontends to SVN (as eg the Emacs mode) let you se t these directly as well avoiding the command-line.